# CSS resize images to fit in div and be reponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using bootstrap3 on a site that allows users to upload images of their own. These images are later displayed in a given page. Problem is, some users upload photos that are either bigger or smaller in respect to the div that'll hold them. I wish to resize all these images using CSS (or even JavaScript if need be) in order for them to fit in the div whilst maintaining their aspect ratio. At the same time, I want them to be responsive.

Comment: `div img { max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; }` will fit in the parent's div

Comment: `div { background-size: cover; }` (only if you're using img on background)

Comment: How do the divs hold the images? By css or by image-tag?

Comment: @PeterRader by image tag...

Comment: Responsive Design should never be done by JavaScript, use CSS for Responsive Design! Therefore a `<img>`-tag is impossible. Show us the HTML to give a clean example and the sizes you like it to be limited to.

Comment: Just one line CSS is enough to fix this issue. `img{max-width:100%;}`. Image will not overflow the div if you make `max-width:100%;`

Comment: .class img{width:100%; height:auto}

Answer (score 0):

Use the `img-responsive` class on your image.

From the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images): "Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element."

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/murkle/10jd0khz/1/

```
function openImageInLightBox(imageBase64) {

div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "myLightboxDiv";
div.style.width = "80%";
div.style.height = "80%";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.top = "10%";
div.style.left= "10%";
div.style.border = "7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
div.style.background = "#000";
div.style["background-image"] = "url('" + imageBase64 + "')";
div.style["background-size"] = "contain";
div.style["background-repeat"] = "no-repeat";
div.style["background-position"] = "center";
div.onclick = function() {document.body.removeChild(div);};

document.body.appendChild(div);

// now add transparent image over it
// so that "Save image as..." works
// remove this if you don't need it
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.src = imageBase64;
elem.style.height = "100%";
elem.style.width = "100%";
elem.style.opacity = 0;
div.appendChild(elem);

}
```